# Annotate term relationships with data via edit form

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, nodes

I'm building a simple download area for a web site. All it should do is to provide material of lectures for users which are grouped into user groups. As I don't want to make the system to difficult I'm not using organic groups or similar but just a share taxonomy between users and my "document" content type. If a document has no terms of that taxonomy or the user has one of the documents terms the document will be shown. Here helps Access by Term (ABT) module perfectly.

However, one caveat is that the publish date of the documents is based on the group. Some groups. Thus some lecturers will use the same document in different courses. To avoid that someone can see the document too early I'd like to add a date to the document/term relationship and filter hide those documents by checking these values in a custom template.

Does anyone know how best to implement such a system. Thinking of adding multiple text fields and letting the editors add TERM NAME|DATE into it. Then I'll loop through all the values on creation of the teaser. Shying a bit away of creating my own module and database table to store maintain these values.

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference. I found a solution: I used the field collection module to implement the needed relationships.